# User and Bot messages appear on same side of chat container

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I built a QnA Maker and integrated it via Direct Line in my Website using [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) for styling.

Messages of the user and the bot are appearing at the same side of the chat container. I can't figure why.

This is how it currently looks like:
[image: I wrote 'Tell me more' and the bot responded]

This is the code I'm using:

```
<script>
  const styleSet = window.WebChat.createStyleSet({
    bubbleFromUserBackground: 'rgba(227, 227, 227, .1)',
    hideUploadButton: true,
    botAvatarInitials: 'WD',
    sendTypingIndicator: true,
    userAvatarInitials: 'you'
  });

  styleSet.textContent = Object.assign(
    {},
    styleSet.textContent,
    {
      fontFamily: '\'Lato\', sans-serif'
    }
  );
  window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
    {
      directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
        token: 'xxxxxx'
      }),
      styleSet,
      userID: 'qna-homepage-bot',
      username: 'Web Chat User',
      locale: 'en-US',
    },
    document.getElementById('webchat')
  );
  document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
</script>
```

Comment: SchweerMarking the solution as accepted serves the greater Stack Overflow community and anyone with a similar question. If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce this, but I suspect you are setting your user ID to the same value as the bot ID. When Web Chat receives an activity, it sets the role property in the activity's from attribute based on the ID (you can take a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/0ebc227913f8d810d6c444197d7a0fc997593a5e/packages/core/src/sagas/incomingActivitySaga.js#L11)). Web Chat then uses the role to determine how the activity is styled. If the bot id equals the user id, Web Chat will confuse the role attribute and apply the wrong CSS stylings. Try changing the `userID` value in the render Web Chat options to something else.

Note, the `userID` value should be unique for each user; otherwise, every conversation will share the same user state.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What is the best practice for setting the userID? The bot we are talking about is a public available qna bot, so I do not have access to any unique user IDs. And is it really a problem if all users get the same userID? There are no context based messages enabled.

Comment: If you don't pass the `userID` as a Prop, Web Chat should generate one for you. If you're not setting and saving state on the bot side, duplicate ID's aren't really a bad thing.